# Use stored procedure or function in SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, stored-procedures, case

I have a couple of questions about how to do what I want with this `SELECT` statement, but the main thing is how to use a function / stored procedure in the `SELECT` statement.

I have something like the example below.

While the Movement bit is small enough to work, the attributes (Strength, Armor, Will, Dexterity) are complex as there aren't restrictions on the order in which number-letter combinations can occur and it needs to be used for 4 different fields.  It makes sense to write a procedure and reuse that 4 times instead of repeating code.

I had attempted to write one for movement, but can't seem to do anything other than `EXEC testProcedure`, even `PRINT( testProcedure 4 )` doesn't seem to work.

Is there a way use a user defined function / procedure on queried field?

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
       Main.CardName, Main.CardType, Main.ProductSet, Main.Movement, Main.Actions, 
       Main.Strength, Main.Armor, Main.Will, Main.Dexterity, Main.Health, 
       Main.Potions, 
( 
    SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT KeywordName )
    FROM HeroesViewMultiLine
    WHERE CardIndex = Main.CardIndex
) AS KeywordCount,
(
    SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT AbilityName )
    FROM HeroesViewMultiLine
    WHERE CardIndex = Main.CardIndex and AbilityResource = 'Action'
) AS ActionCount, 
(
    SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT AbilityName )
    FROM HeroesViewMultiLine
    WHERE CardIndex = Main.CardIndex and AbilityResource = 'Potion' 
) AS SkillCount,
(
    --Movement
    ( 
        SELECT CASE 
            WHEN Main.Movement = 5 THEN 1
            WHEN Main.Movement = 6 THEN 1
            WHEN Main.Movement = 7 THEN 3
            WHEN Main.Movement = 8 THEN 3
            WHEN Main.Movement = 9 THEN 6
            WHEN Main.Movement = 10 THEN 6
            ELSE 0
        END
    )
    --Actions
    +(Main.Actions),
    --STR
    +(
        SELECT CASE 
            WHEN Main.Strength = 5 THEN 1
            
            ELSE 0
        END
    )
    --ARM
    +(SELECT CASE 
        WHEN Main.Armor = 5 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END)
    --WILL
    +(SELECT CASE 
        WHEN Main.Will = 5 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END)
    --DEX
    +(SELECT CASE 
        WHEN Main.Dexterity = 5 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END)
    --Health
    +(Main.Health)
    --Potions
    +(Main.Potions)
    --KeywordCount
    +(SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT KeywordName )
    FROM HeroesViewMultiLine
    WHERE CardIndex = Main.CardIndex)
    --ActionCount
    +(SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT AbilityName )
    FROM HeroesViewMultiLine
    WHERE CardIndex = Main.CardIndex and AbilityResource = 'Action')
    --SkillCount
    +(SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT AbilityName )
    FROM HeroesViewMultiLine
    WHERE CardIndex = Main.CardIndex and AbilityResource = 'Potion' )
) AS BONUSES

FROM HeroesViewMultiLine Main
```

Comment: You cannot invoke stored procedures in the middle of a select statement. You can invoke [scalar-valued user-defined functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql#a-using-a-scalar-valued-user-defined-function-that-calculates-the-iso-week) and [table-valued user-defined functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql#b-creating-an-inline-table-valued-function), however.

Comment: Maybe you can make a SP for above all like sp_player_basic_info

Comment: Or you can capture the results of your SP into a temp table and join.

Comment: Your query only select from one single table `HeroesViewMultiLine` and you have so many sub-query selecting from the same table. I have no idea what you are trying to achieve here, but it seems not efficient. Try rewrite using `GROUP BY`, and use `CASE` expression for the conditional aggregation

Comment: @Squirrel In the spirit of one question per post, so I didn't include the concerns there.  Most likely the columns sub selected will be removed.  The point of this is to do analysis on the table, the only "important" part is the Bonus total at the end.

Comment: @YunHan gets full marks, creating the functions correctly (I was having a time figuring it out for some reason) seems to be to work for the movement part.  Hopefully it should be easy enough to do all the attribute logic in a function as well.  Thank you!  (If you want to transfer the comment to an answer, I'd be happy to select it.)

Comment: If that is your full query, I don't think it is complex enough to justify for use of function or maybe stored procedure to generate intermediate result into temp table for later query. Depending on how you use it, function may result in not performant query. My advice is try rewrite the query as my suggestion earlier. If you have issue, ask in a new question.

Comment: @Squirrel it seems to be fairly performant so far, the sub selects just get me counts I need for what is basically a report on a view.  If I need to actually display this somewhere, then I will likely make it a view as I'll need to join on other views, but, for now, putting all this in a stored procedure is fine.

Answer (score 0):

There are many different methods to get Stored Procedure’s results in the SELECT statement, such as creating a temp table, creating a table variable, using functions, and many more. However, here is the easiest method to run the stored procedure in SELECT statement.

For example here is the SP which you want to execute:

```
EXEC [AdventureWorks].[dbo].[uspGetManagerEmployees] 5
GO
```

You can run the following SELECT statement with the help of OPENROWSET and execute the stored procedure.

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI',
'server=localhost;trusted_connection=yes;',
'EXEC [AdventureWorks].[dbo].[uspGetManagerEmployees] 5')
GO
```

Yes, indeed it is that easy. When you run the SELECT statement with OPENROWSET and if you get an error about ad hoc queries, you can run the following command to fix the error.

```
Msg 15281, Level 16, State 1
SQL Server blocked access to STATEMENT ‘OpenRowset/OpenDatasource’ of component ‘Ad Hoc Distributed Queries’ because this component is turned off as part of the security configuration for this server. A system administrator can enable the use of ‘Ad Hoc Distributed Queries’ by using sp_configure. For more information about enabling ‘Ad Hoc Distributed Queries’, search for ‘Ad Hoc Distributed Queries’ in SQL Server Books Online.

sp_configure 'Show Advanced Options', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
```

Comment: This might be what I'm looking for.  The alternative seems to be select into a variable in a stored procedure process, and repeat.